# Asterisk Forbidden Error

Tags: java, sip, asterisk

When I try to perform authentication process in asterisk by using jain sip library, it gave 200 ok message for only one extension , but I tried same code for different extension , it shows 'Forbidden' message. I have verified credential I have passed in my program

Comment: Its too broad An error can be caused by lot of problem. Please post more info the code or a flow diagram of wha you have done.

Answer (score 1):

Forbidden can be caused by

1) incorrect realm. You are using no realm= line in sip.conf or using other realm

2) incorrect password

3) incorrect nat settings.

Answer (score 0):

Generally This error occur when u enter the hostname instead of the IP address.